# Como puedo calcular la columna saldo de una tabla mysql?, como si fuera el estado de cuenta de un banco

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La sentencia SQL que tengo no hace el calculo correcto, lo que yo espero es:

```
   saldo
   100
    50
    40
   340
   370
```

Comment: Publica lo que has hecho hasta ahora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías resolverlo usando una [variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html).

#### Ejemplo:

```
SET @acumulador=0;

SELECT
    concepto,
    cargo,
    abono,
    @acumulador:=(cargo - abono + @acumulador) AS saldo
FROM poliza_detalles;
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55a336/1)</kbd>

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, consulta definitiva: SELECT concepto, cargo, abono, @acumulador:=(cargo - abono + @acumulador) AS saldo FROM poliza_detalles WHERE cuenta_id = 1